# vb.net cycle through controls not working

Tags: vb.net, foreach, controls, master-pages, asp.net-webpages

I'm trying to cycle through the controls on a page that consists of textboxes and a dropdown and clear them.

When I debug, parent is the current page, value is equal to ASP.nameOfCurrentpage_aspx and 
Type is equal to system.web.ui.page, but c has the value of ASP.site_master and type of system.web.ui.control.  I also put in x to see how many controls it finds and x comes back as 1 even though there are 15 or so textboxes on the page.  Is there a way I can force c to have the value of ASP.nameOfCurrentpage_aspx?  Or is that not my problem?  Any help is appreciated.

```
Protected Sub btnClear_Click(sender as Object, e as System.eventargs) Handles btnClear.Click
   ClearForm(Page)

End Sub

Public Sub ClearForm(ByRef Parent As Control)
    Dim c As Control
    Dim x As Integer = Parent.Controls.Count
    For Each c In Parent.Controls
        If c.GetType.ToString = "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm" Then
            ClearForm(c)
        ElseIf c.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox) Then
            'is it a Text Box?
            Dim t As TextBox = c
            t.Text = ""
        ElseIf c.GetType() Is GetType(DropDownList) Then
            'is it a dropdown list?
            Dim d As DropDownList = c
            d.ClearSelection()
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you every for your help.  I didn't try all of the answers but I used them for ideas.  This is what we came up with at work and it finds and clears all the controls on the page. We had to find the content place holder linked to the master site (cph).  Again thanks for all the suggestions.

```
Public Sub ClearForm(ByRef Parent As Control)
    Dim cph As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder = Master.FindControl("MainBody")
    Dim c As Control
    Dim x As Integer = Parent.Controls.Count
    For Each c In cph.Controls
        If c.GetType.ToString = "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm" Then
            ClearForm(c)
        ElseIf c.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox) Then
            'is it a Text Box?
            Dim t As TextBox = c
            t.Text = ""
        ElseIf c.GetType() Is GetType(DropDownList) Then
            'is it a dropdown list?
            Dim d As DropDownList = c
            d.ClearSelection()
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTMLForm Control is probably nested, likely under a MasterPage.  Either go fully recursive with your function or add a clause in your If Statement that looks for the Master Page.  This is where breakpoints and the Watch Window are gold.

Ex:

```
ElseIf c.GetType.ToString = "ASP.MasterPageName_Master" Then
   ClearForm(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I programmed anything in .NET with controls, MVC has spoiled me silly, or using VB.NET...

However I am thinking you will probably need to recurse through the stack of controls:

```
Protected Sub btnClear_Click(sender as Object, e as System.eventargs) Handles btnClear.Click
   ClearForm(Page)

End Sub

Public Sub ClearForm(ByRef Parent As Control)
    Dim c As Control
    Dim x As Integer = Parent.Controls.Count
    For Each c In Parent.Controls
        If c.GetType.ToString = "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm" Then
            ClearForm(c)
        ElseIf c.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox) Then
            'is it a Text Box?
            Dim t As TextBox = c
            t.Text = ""
        ElseIf c.GetType() Is GetType(DropDownList) Then
            'is it a dropdown list?
            Dim d As DropDownList = c
            d.ClearSelection()
        ElseIf c.Controls != null ' Does VB.NET support nulls? I forget
            ClearForm(c.Controls)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: != null in VB Syntax is "IsNot Nothing" or "Not c.controls Is Nothing"